# How to create an array with Character in count String in Swift 5.5

Tags: arrays, swift, string, count, character

```
var myStr = "Swift"

let myCh: Character = "S"

var myArr = Array(repeating: String(myCh), count: myStr.count)
myArr        //   ["S", "S", "S", "S", "S"]
```

This code doesn't work in swift 5.5, how can i repeat it in other way?

Comment: It's unclear, what do you expect? What's your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var myStr = "Swift"
let myCh: Character = "S"
var myArr = [String]()

myStr.forEach {_ in
    myArr.append("\(myCh)")
}

print(myArr)
```